# print(1 >> (10 ^ 0xAAAA)) is 0. However, it is different in c language

Tags: python, c

For python:

```
print(1 >> (10 ^ 0xAAAA))
```

The result is 0.

For c language:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  long int x=10;
  long int a = x ^ 0xAAAA;
  int b = 1 >> a;
  printf("a: %x\n", a);
  printf("b: %d\n", b);
}
```

The result b=1.

For x=1,100 etc.. The outputs of python and c codes are all 0. 
Given x=10, the outputs are different. 
Why?

Comment: Because both are different languages and support different standard.

Comment: For x =1,100 etc... The outputs are the same. Given x=10, the outputs are different.

Comment: c overflow, python doesnt

Comment: Different languages may do the same thing or do different things. Is there an element of surprise here?

Comment: In C, you are shifting `1` by more `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1` (which on most platforms translates to "more than 31"). This leads to undefined behavior AFAIK. The compiler probably takes the number of bits to shift modulo 32, i.e., `(10 ^ 0xAAAA) % 32`, which is equal to 0. Hence `1 << (10 ^ 0xAAAA)` gives you 1.

Comment: @n.m. Given x=10,  the output of c language is 1, while the output of python is 0. Given x=1 or 100 or 1000, the outputs are all 0. According to the bit operation, the outputs should be 0 with arbitrary small x.

Comment: You seem to assume all languages must faithfully follow some kind of celestial law when it comes to bit operations. This is not the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python you can right shift as much as you want, and it'll give you always the correct result (which, for a shift amount big enough, will always be zero); in C instead right-shifting of more than the type size is undefined behavior ([C99,  §6.5.7 ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.7p3); the same holds for the left shift), which means that the compiler is free to emit code that does anything in that particular case.

The point of having undefined behavior in all "strange cases" of bit shifting is to let the compiler translate shifts in C code straight to whatever shift instructions the target platform provides and obtain the best performance; in your particular case, probably you are running your program on x86, where the C right shift gets translated straight to a [SHR or SAR instruction. These take only the low 5 bits of the shift amount](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html), so it becomes a right shift of zero places, hence the result.